# qca-ossl plugin not loading. Showing error: HMAC(SHA1) is not supported

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, qt

I have ported the application from Qt4.8.5 to Qt5.5.0 and from Xcode 5 to Xcode 7 at the same time.
After porting, the openssl libraries are provided externally as they are no longer provided by Apple.

Now when I run my application, I get this error:

```
HMAC(SHA1) is not supported!
```

The primary reason for this is that qca is not able to load qca-ossl plugin but don't know that why it is not loading. The closest relation to this problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765496/cannot-load-qca-ossl-in-qt5-application) but its not exact issue and doesn't solve the issue.

The QCA version I am using is 2.1.0 and qca-ossl is 2.0.0 with openssl 1.0.2e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working now!
Had to additionally declare macro:

```
#define QT_VERSION 0x050500
```

This is because Qt’s MOC couldn’t pick the version and was still taking Qt4 code and hence not making it a valid plugin. Have reported a bug in Qt [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51028) for the same.